# How can I get the current ECS hosting EC2 IAM RoleName from the ECS Task?

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-iot

How can I get the current ECS hosting EC2 IAM RoleName from the ECS Task? I'm using dotnet core.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to retrieve the current IAM role from *inside a running ECS task*.

Use the AWS SDK for .NET:

```
var response = client.GetCallerIdentity(new GetCallerIdentityRequest 
{
});

string account = response.Account;
string arn = response.Arn;
string userId = response.UserId;
```